# How to save the csv file in python with filename as "abc_soi_Today'sdate-1"

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to save get request data in csv format using python, the objective is to save the data in csv in a defined folder with filename as "abc_soi_today's date-1". for example

case 1:
if i run the code today i.e. 15th july 2021 then the file name should be "abc_soi_20210714"

case 2:
if i run the code on monday then it should take the file name date of friday, for example if i had ran it on 12th July 2017, it'd have taken filename as "abc_soi_20210709"

Also, by any chance can i also change the sheet name from sheet1 to "abc_soi_today'sdate-1" based on which date i am running.

```
 import urllib.request as req

def download_csv(download_url):
    request = req.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open("C:\\Users\\amul\\Desktop\\test.csv", 'wb')
    file.write(request.read())
    file.close()

download_csv("http://uspvalpc064:8080/python-toolkit/barclayst/file?source=dataDelivery&type=soi&destination=pv&asof=20210714")
```

[image]

Comment: Get today's date, time delta it one day prior, then format it. Pass that formatted date to the path you want to save at. Save the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` to generate the desired file name:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
file_name = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

print(file_name)
20210714
```

Comment: i tried using 
def download_csv(download_url):
    request = req.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open("C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\test.csv", 'wb')
yesterday = datetime.now()-timedelta(1)
test = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print(test)

Comment: but it's still saving it with file name as test

Comment: U need to replace what is inside open() with the generated file name

Comment: i have this inside open (file = open("C:\\Users\\amul\\Desktop\\test.csv", 'wb'))

Comment: Yes that is what is defining the file name.

Comment: and can i put these two lines anywhere in my existing code ?
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)


C:\\Users\\amul\\Desktop\\test.csv = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

Comment: ah i am still getting some error, can you please help me wht should be the correct code here

Comment: Yes, do open("C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\" + file_name + '.csv', 'wb'), where file_name is the line I told you previously.

Comment: ("C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\" + test + '.csv', 'wb') = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
     ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234965/discussion-between-franco-piccolo-and-naina).